# How do I get the final smelter wedge in the DLC of the Old Iron King?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am confused. I have read a few articles about the final smelter wedge in the DLC for DarkSouls2 and they are not very clear. I am at the Fume Knight but it said in the walkthrough that you need to beat the fume knight to get the final smelter wedge and then you can Interact with the armor to fight Sir Alonne, but here's the rub: The fume knight will keep healing back up if you have any Nadalia totems left, but how are you supposed to get rid of the final totem if the Fume knight has to be defeated to get it? I need clarity. Any help would be appreciated.

Postnote: it's sixteen days later and now I realize that you don't need the final smelter wedge to interact with the armor and enter Sir Alonne's memory. You need the "Ashen Mist heart" from Dragon Aerie and 10 of the 11 smelter wedges. That is how to do it.

Comment: You can un-accept an answer by clicking the check mark again.

Comment: Just keep him on the other half of the area, it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a total of 11 smelter wedges that can be found in the following locations:

> - Six near the beginning.
> - Four close to the third bonfire, take the elevator to the left up twice and go right at the top of the second elevator, follow the path and at the end is a chest with four Smelter Wedges.
> - One on a throne after the Sir Alonne boss fight. Only accessible after Fume Knight is defeated.
>
> [Wiki source](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/smelter-wedge)

There does not appear to be a way of getting the last smelter wedge if you've already used up 8 smelter wedges prior to Fume Knight. This appears to be one of many ways in which you are taught to not just do certain actions, but really think them through.

Answer (score 0):

To defeat the Fume Knight, there are several tactics you can employ to kill him. The main difference is the healers around the room. If you go outside the arena, there are several enemies that will periodically heal the Fume Knight during the fight. Your options are to either kill them, or keep him out of their range. Directly in the centre of the arena is usually the best place, however it is a bit tricky to keep him there.

Then, to interact with Sir Alonne's armour, you will need the [Ashen Mist Heart](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Ashen+Mist+Heart). This is the item that let's you enter a Memory, and in this case, the Memory of the Old Iron King.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. @Rhaunn asked for directions to the final smelter wedge, not tactics to defeat Fume Knight.

Comment: Honestly I'm not entirely sure what the question was about. Je spoke about the fume knight, the smelter wedges, and interacting with the armour, so I got a little lost

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Daniel, I think you are probably right. The DarkSouls series are unforgiving and so I think your answer makes the most sense. Even the walkthroughs for wiki and IGN are unclear on this matter. One of the walkthroughs says you will get the final smelter wedge off the body of the Fume Knight. I  can say definitively you don't get the final smelter wedge off the defeated Fume Knight now.